# How can I use input/output text files in Clion?

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

I want to import .txt file in my C project in Clion for test if my code is ok.
I want to automate the command that I run in bash:

`./<executable_name> < input.txt | diff -output.txt`

Comment: You need to read the documentation about creation/editing Run Configuration. Here it is:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

You have to fill "Program Arguments".